# Why does blender render faster when I’m moving the mouse?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hardware

So this is a bit of a weird question. But I rendered a scene and it took 19.54 minutes, but if while I was rendering it, I clicked and moved the mouse a bunch, it took 17.52 minutes. It’s not a problem but I am just curious why.

Thanks
Daniel

(If you’re reading this, I will add screenshots later, I am not at my pc right now lol)

Comment: Does the same apply in "both directions" (click on first run and no click on the second run and then the inverse )? I'm wondering if blender builds the BVH for each mesh on the first run but doesn't need to rebuild without significant modification, so it's able to "skip" that step on the second (and each subsequent) render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when rendering for the first time the shaders are compiled, for next renders this is not needed, as they are mostly retrieved from cash